# ContactsContract. Как получить все номера телефонов только от аккаунта Google?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Получаем из ContactsContract айдишник контакта так:

```
Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));//получаем id контакта
```

Потом вытаскиваем все телефоны из контакта:

```
Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String PhoneCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        PhoneCONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        PhoneCONTACT_ID + " =?",
                        new String[]{contact_id},
                        null);
String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
```

Проблема в том, что мы получаем вообще все телефоны контакта, которые у него есть, включая те, который были туда внесены всякими Viber, Skype и прочими Ватсапами. Получается, что один и тот же набор цифр повторяется несколько раз (только с вариантами написания).

**Вопрос:** Как получить только те номера телефонов, которые внесены в базу из аккаунта Google и самого устройства?